# Dynamic Data website only displays rows that it inserted to DB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm pretty new to creating dynamic data websites - I created one a year ago that is working fine but now I'm trying a 2nd one and having a strange problem.

I'm using VS2010, VB.net & followed MS's waltkthrough for creating a web site using Linq to SQL. Things seem to be working with one MAJOR exception.  I've pointed it to a SQL server in my domain but it won't display rows from the DB that were not created through the website.  Records that I manually enter through SSMS do not show in the DD List for the table, but rows I inserted thru the website do appear.

I have cleared the table and refreshed the list view and all rows disappear.  Then if I add rows via SSMS they do NOT show up but website added ones do.  This is important because I'm going to be importing data from an old (non SQL) DB that I'm converting.

I really don't know where to look to resolve this - Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check you connection string. it seem like you are point to diff database then the one you are connect with SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

The records I entered thru ssms had bad values for a foreign key and evidently DD is doing inner joins instead of left outer. I don't know if that is a bug or a feature.